# adabas system date

Tags: database, non-relational-database

I need the system date of the database, the database is `adabas`. Attunity use to access the database, I find no information on google or the official site.

Something like in Oracle database:

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM dual;
```

Comment: What product are you using to access Adabas? Most customers use Natural which has a number of different Date & Time System-Variables. For example *DATN, which contains the Date in Format YYYYMMDD (N8).

Answer (score 1):

get date from adabas by using  `current_date()`

```
 select  current_date()
```